# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished while setting up first rails app on Ruby on Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am just starting out on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl and I have run into a problem running my first rails server. Instead of the normal default application page, I receive an ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished error that I have not been able to solve.

**My GemFile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.16'
group :development do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
```

**My database.yml**

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

**Full Trace**

```
activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__105514737__call__333040863__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

**Full Trace After doing Max's suggestions:**

```
activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.16) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__733682894__call__567347261__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.16) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Two things: 1. try changing `gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'` to `gem 'sqlite3'`, 2. Try moving `gem 'sqlite3'` out of the :development group (put it above)

Comment: Hey Max that didn't work. Get the same error

Comment: also, where is this tutorial you are following? Just so I can better help

Comment: This is the book: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2#sec-bundler

Comment: I updated the new full trace after doing your suggested edits

Comment: have you been doing ``bundle update`` and ``bundle install`` in between the changes? As well as stopping the server, and starting a new one?

Comment: Yes, I have for every change

Comment: Okay, what is the output from `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_get(:@config)[:database]` ?

Comment: How do I get the output?

Comment: try puts & inspect, and watching the console output

Comment: Sorry Max, I am a complete noob at this. Is there a way we can do this over to chat?

Comment: Does it help if I tell you I am on a Windows 8 machines?

Comment: Try this? https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12559

Comment: I am running Rails 3.2.16 though?

Comment: Sure, but it says you need 20 rep to chat

Answer (score 0):

There's no database to connect to yet, I reckon. Run `rake db:create`.

Comment: Nope, I tried this from viewing other answers. It's telling me my db already exists